# Run function when background mode is active using ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, background-mode

I am using the ionic [Background Mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) plugin. First, I installed in the project, imported in the app.module.ts file and put this code in app.component.ts file `this.backgroundMode.enable();`. I want to check if background mode is active in the background run function. I want to run my function when the background mode is active.

```
let inBackground = true;

this.backgroundMode.isActive();

this.myfunction();
```

Does anyone know how to do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to do it as in example below:

```
this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(s => {
        console.log('backgroundMode activate');
 });
 this.backgroundMode.enable();
```

More information about it you can take from this
[Cordova Background Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
```

And in your constructor

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
            // Call your method here
        });

        this.backgroundMode.enable();
    });
}
```